# yii2 DETAILS VIEW "htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: yii2

This is my view file inside details views

```
                 [
                   'label'=>'Unit ID',
                    'value'=>function($model){
                            $data = json_decode($model->unit_id);
                              $number = count($data);

                              for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
                                return  substr(implode(", ", $data), 0);
                                        }
                          }
                 ],
```

But It keep giving me error `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string`.

Then I tried to call it as function I created at model file

```
 public function unit($model)
    {
         $data = json_decode($model->unit_id);
                 $number = count($data);

                 for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
             return  substr(implode(", ", $data), 0);
                 }
    }
```

then for my view file

```
[
         'label'=>'Unit Id',
          'value'=>unit($model),
 ],
```

but I get error `call to undefined function`

Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: What's the point of `for` loop if you return something immediately inside?

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED it. This is the solution using the call function method.

```
function unit($model)
    {
         $data = json_decode($model->unit_id);
                 $number = count($data);

                 for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++){
             return  substr(implode(", ", $data), 0);
                 }
    }
```

In view file

```
[
         'label'=>'Unit Id',
          'value'=>$model->unit($model),
 ],
```

Comment: Do you know, u don't have to pass `$model` here? Just use `$this` in function. Then you can rename function to `function getUnit()`, and in `DetailView` simply use `$model->unit`. Anyway, check the answer with Yii version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Yii2 version, propably you have < 2.0.11, because `value` can be provided as closure since version 2.0.11.
[Proof here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-detailview.html#$attributes-detail)